# How to skip invoking another method to create a mock object?

Tags: easymock

I have a class of methods, if I want to test one method, but the objects created in this method depend on other methods in the class. I don't want to actually call the other methods, I just want to create mock objects to test. How should I do it?

```
@Test
public void testLoadException(String id) {

    WorkflowExecution mockWorkflowExection = getWorkflowExecution(id);

}
```

I tried to just do so

```
WorkflowExecution mockExecution = EasyMock.create(WorkflowExecution.class);
Easy.expect(this.test.getWorkflowExecution(EasyMock.anyString())).andReturn(mockExecution);
```

But this does not work, the test gives me `Nullpointer exception`.
So can I skip the calling of `getWorkflowExecution(id)`, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a partial mock. Your example doesn't make much sense. So here is what you seem to want.

```
public class WorkflowExecution {
    public void theRealMethodIWantToCall() {
        theMethodIWantToMock();
    }

    void theMethodIWantToMock() {

    }
}

@Test
public void testLoadException() {
    WorkflowExecution execution = partialMockBuilder(WorkflowExecution.class)
            .addMockedMethod("theMethodIWantToMock")
            .mock();
    execution.theMethodIWantToMock();
    replay(execution);

    execution.theRealMethodIWantToCall();

    verify(execution);
}
```